# Riggig character

Tags: animation, rigging

I tried to rig my character for the animation but i am unable to do it. I am creating a dinosaur for my college project and i gave all the armature of the character in the edit mode but after i go to the pose mode, the skeleton of the body changes automatically and i cannot fix that issue. Can any one help me with this.
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Did you do parenting?

Answer (score 0):

Select the Armature in Object Mode, then switch to Pose Mode, and look in the Object Data tab of the Properties Panel, under the Skeleton Section. There is a button called Rest Pose. Press it.

[image]

After doing this, note whether the rig is now in the position you consider appropriate for the default pose. If it is, then press Ctrl-A, and from the menu that pops up, choose Apply Pose as Rest Pose.

[image]

Now go back to the Skeleton Section and press the button labeled "Pose Position" (this step is essential. If you don't switch back to Pose Position afterwards, your rig will not move). Nothing will appear to change with your rig's pose after doing this, but now you have a rest pose that is consistent between the various modes. It should no longer jump when switching between them.

If you find when pressing the Rest Pose button under the Skeleton section that the messed up version of the pose is the one that your rig reverts to, instead of the proper one, then the above instructions won't work. Instead, you'll need to go into Edit Mode and adjust the bones that are not posed properly, such as by zeroing out the bone roll values, or by aligning the local axes throughout the bone chains so that the local Y is pointing straight down the length of all of them. Always remember that the position of your bones in Edit Mode IS your default position for the bones before they receive any transform tweaks.